# Shiro session timeout not working in Heroku

Tags: java, session, heroku, shiro, spark-java

We have encountered an issue regarding session timeout in our webapp currently deployed in Heroku. Our app is built using Spark java and Shiro. Session timeout is currently set in our shiro.ini like this:

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionManager.sessionIdUrlRewritingEnabled = false
sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 86400000
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
```

Session timeout works perfectly when running locally on a tomcat server but once deployed in heroku the session timeout reverts to the default session timeout which is 30 minutes.

We've also tried removing the lines above in our shiro.ini and setting session timeout in the web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

but the session timeout when deployed in heroku is still 30 minutes. Has anyone experienced the same?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Procfile

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT --session-timeout 1440 target/*.war
```

**SOLVED**

The issue with the timeout is caused by using a free dyno that sleeps after 30 mins of inactivity as stated in the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours), and not a Shiro session timeout problem. Thanks to @codefinger for helping out!

Comment: Are you confident that the `shino.ini` is being read on Heroku? Does changing any of the other properties have an effect? If you set `globalSessionTimeout` to 5 minutes, does the session on Heroku timeout at 5 minutes?

Comment: Do you have a proc file?  A Heroku app should start pretty much the same way locally if you run the command from proc file.

Comment: @codefinger Hi, thank you for replying. Yes, we tried setting it to 5 mins and it's working properly. Is the problem setting it greater than the default session timeout?

Comment: @BrianDemers Hi thanks for the reply. I updated the post and added the procfile. I use this code to run locally: java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war

Comment: That confirms the ini file is read. Is this on a free dyno? Is the dyno going to sleep (which would clear the in-mem session)?

Comment: @codefinger Hi thanks for helping me out. Yup, we're using free dyno at the moment and yes it will sleep as stated in the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours).

Comment: If the session state is stored in memory, and the dyno goes to sleep, the session will effectively expire. You'll need to store it in Redis or Memcached.

Comment: @codefinger Okay, thanks! I'll try to store it in memcache and inform you of the results.

Comment: @codefinger Had a talk with the team and decided not to store the session in Redis or Memcached because the issue would most likely be solved if we used a paid dyno. Anyways thanks for helping out! Cheers!